# Saving File Path Using File Picker

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the below code via a user form with buttons. On the form, I have created three (3) separate command buttons that are to save different file paths to open existing excel workbooks. The idea is to have vba automatically open/close workbooks in a completely automated fashion.

```
Dim SCDMMRReport As FileDialog
Dim ActionClicked As Boolean

Set SCDMMRReport = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

SCDMMRReport.InitialFileName = "J:\INS\CAS\G22 PRT Report"
SCDMMRReport.AllowMultiSelect = False

ActionClicked = SCDMMRReport.Show

If ActionClicked Then
   SCDMMRReportCommandButton.Visible = False
   SCDMMRReportLabel.BackColor = rgbLightGreen
   SCDMMRCheckBox = True
Else
    MsgBox ("No file selected!")
    SCDMMRReportCommandButton.BackColor = rgbPink
    SCDMMRReportLabel.BackColor = rgbPink
End If
```

Everything appears as it runs excellent, however when it comes time to call on this code later in the script (when I hit the execute command button), the file paths are not saved. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Derek

Comment: When code execution ends, the value of variables is reset. you need to save that info in a non volatile way. (in a hidden sheet for example)

Comment: "the file paths are not saved" - this is because you don't put them anywhere...

Comment: If you are in a user form it creates a unique challenge to variable scope, Module or Sub wise, If you only Show/Hide the form and don't destroy it you will be able to hold onto those Variants once you assign them.  If you put them at the top of the module and pass the variables out by reference (if you call outside of form module code) you can change those variables outside of the form module.

Comment: If you want to pick folder, then you should use `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` instead of `msoFileDialogFilePicker`. In any case, you can then store the selected path/file in a var with `MySelectedItem = SCDMMRReport.SelectedItems(1)

Comment: Thanks for the posts! I figured it was a retention error and has been fixed!